# Mac Chrome bookmarks folders are gray

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bookmarks

I was looking for answers and I can't find any. How can I make the bookmarks folders yellow again?

A similar question was asked [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0xRyzrGvFTQk?hl=en) but is not helpful.

They are gray on my mac, however in my windows pc they are yellow. I'm using the latest version of chrome and the data is the same on both OS. Even a clean install would remain the same on mac.

[image]

Can I make them yellow on mac?

Comment: The icon isn't actually grey but it is greyscale and blends with the background colour of your theme. Looking at various Google Chrome theme creators there doesn't appear to be the option to change this but I could be wrong.

Comment: @unknowndomain the theme is not part of the problem

Comment: I am not saying the theme is the issue, I am saying that the folder is not grey, it's white and transparent white and that the colour of the theme influences this, if you pick a crazy coloured theme you get a folder of that colour because it's tinted by the theme. However the theme doesn't appear to have a parameter for setting a different icon asset.

Comment: I have the same problem with Google Chrome and Brave Browser on Linux... bookmark folders are grey instead of yellow as they are in those browsers in Windows. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy seems like google is not going to fix it, I switched to Firefox